# Python FOR loop with range is repeating and skipping part of the code in the first run and repeating that code in its next run

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Using Python with Selenium to automate filling a time sheet in a page having several collapsible options.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ci8B.png

Below code is collapsing Monday, selecting the "breakout" option, then collapsing Tuesday, doing nothing, goes back to Monday again and does what's required but does nothing for the part against "breakout" this time and then exits. In reality, I want it to collapse Monday, select the options, fill time using send keys; then collapse Tuesday, select the options, fill time using send keys; and then exit printing "All days filled".Time is getting filled as [16:59] and [17:59] instead of [16:00] and [17:00]. "All days filled" is never getting printed.

```
for i in range(2):
    if i == 2:
        print("All days filled")
        break
    CollapseList[i].click()
    project = wait_for_xpath(driver, "//select[@id='gvTimesheetDay0_ctl02_ddlPANPA']/option[@value='1']").click()
    print("Project Selected")
    some_app_name = wait_for_xpath(driver,
                         "//select[@id='gvTimesheetDay0_ctl02_ddlProject']/option[@value='000043']").click()
    print("App selected")
    wrk = wait_for_xpath(driver,
                         "//select[@id='gvTimesheetDay0_ctl02_ddlPayCode']/option[@value='000000000000318']").click()
    print("Code selected")
    time_in = wait_for_visibility(driver, "gvTimesheetDay0_ctl02_txtSignIn").send_keys("08:00")
    timeout = wait_for_visibility(driver, "gvTimesheetDay0_ctl02_txtSignOut").send_keys("16:00")
    breakout = wait_for_xpath(driver, "//select[@id='ddlMealBreak0']/option[@value='2']").click()
    # press = wait_for_visibility(driver, "lnkSubmit0").click()
    # print("Good " + Day[n] + " has been filled")
    # justclick = wait_for_xpath(driver, "//html").click()
    print(i)
```

Comment: Please indent your code. What you've pasted here isn't valid so we can't provide accurate feedback.

Comment: I have done it now.

Comment: Have you tried to execute code step by step (with debugger) to find out if e.g. `CollapseList[i].click()` does what it should do and if the xpaths lead to the expected positions?

Comment: For instance the `@id='gvTimesheetDay0...` parts look as if they always relate to day 0 (monday).

Comment: You're right it should be gvTimesheetDay0, ...Day1, ...Day2 and so on. How do I change it inside the loop? Sorry I am very new to both Python and Selenium.

Comment: Never mind, fixed it like this:

    DayIn = "gvTimesheetDay" + str(i) + "_ctl02_txtSignIn"
    DayOut = "gvTimesheetDay" + str(i) + "_ctl02_txtSignOut"
    time_in = wait_for_visibility(driver, DayIn).send_keys("08:00")
    timeout = wait_for_visibility(driver, DayOut).send_keys("16:00")